# UINAvigationController -> setViewControllers causes a crash

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I've a very strange situation here - call of the [method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621861-setviewcontrollers?language=objc) `UINAvigationController -> setViewControllers:animated:` causes a crash of the app. It's happining only on iOS 10.3.2 and when I'm building the app in release mode.

I've collected more details. Hope they can help to understand what happens.

The issue appears on iOS 10.3.2 and in release mode only. I’ve checked this on iPhone with 10.3.2 and release build fails but debug works OK. Additionally, I’ve checked previous version of the app from AppStore on iOS 10.3.2 and it’s OK too. Debug and release builds work fine on all of the previous versions of iOS.

The previous version in AppStore was built with older version of Xcode, and now I'm using latest Xcode 8.3.2. I suppose it's system issue, which is related to iOS and Xcode versions.

Regarding sources, it looks like:

AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    ...
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    ....
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
    window.rootViewController = navigationController
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    continueButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(navigateForward), for: .touchUpInside)
    ...
}

func navigateForward(sender: UIButton!) {
    let nextController = FinalBuilder.viewController()
    navigationController?.setViewControllers([nextController], animated: true)
}
```

I said before, it works fine in all cases except one :). `UINAvigationController -> setViewControllers:animated:` is standard iOS method, available from iOS 3.0+ and not deprecated now. There are no hacks or something else what can corrupt the program flow. And it’s usual way to use it.

P.S. There is no debug log or any other message which I can provide you because the app just disappears from the screen with no notification at all.

Comment: Can you paste the exact crash error message ?

Comment: There is no error message. I've mentioned it in description.

Comment: So how did you get to know that `setViewControllers` caused the crash ?

Comment: Because crash won't happen without this call :). If I'm using pushViewController method instead, it works fine. Anyway, I figured out what was the real cause of the issue. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that this behavior appeared after update of RxCocoa from 3.3.1 to 3.4.0. It happens because of the following change in `DelegateProxyType.swift : extension ObservableType : func subscribeProxyDataSource`:

```
     return Disposables.create { [weak object] in
         subscription.dispose()
-       unregisterDelegate.dispose()
         object?.layoutIfNeeded()
+       unregisterDelegate.dispose()
     }
```

I've posted report to [ReactiveX/RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1271) repository. You can check final state there, if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

if its not work , so you can try easy way like

simple creat view controller object and pass in navigation

```
let nextVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"ScrollViewController") as! ScrollViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
```